# Python. Цикл с модулем time (временный цикл)

Tags: python-3.x, циклы, while

Здравствуйте! Хочу написать для своей игры улучшение, которое будет действовать в течении 30 секунд. Для этого воспользовался модулем time и создал цикл while.

```
import time
# timeout variable can be omitted, if you use specific value in the while 
condition
timeout = 300   # [seconds]

timeout_start = time.time()

while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
    test = 0
    if test == 5:
        break
    test -= 1
#Пример
print('example')
```

Но это меня не устраивает, поскольку print('example') выполнится лишь по завершению цикла while.
Я решил использовать вот такой цикл, что тоже мне не подходит потому, что example выводится на экран во время работы цикла while слишком часто.

```
import time
# timeout variable can be omitted, if you use specific value in the while 
condition
timeout = 300   # [seconds]

timeout_start = time.time()

while time.time() < timeout_start + timeout:
    test = 0
    if test == 5:
        break
    test -= 1
    #Пример
    print('example')
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему. Мне нужно, чтобы во время использования улучшения игра продолжала работать.

Comment: Несколько не понятен вопрос. Что значит фраза "чтобы во время использования улучшения игра продолжала работать."? Ваша игра перестает работать на время выполнения цикла, а нужно что бы продолжала? и по истечении 30 секунд выполнила какое-то действие (print('example'))?

Comment: Фраза "чтобы во время использования улучшения игра продолжала работать" означает, что когда игрок касается улучшения игра не останавливалась, то есть программа продолжала работать, как раньше . Программа во время выполнения цикла останавливает свою работу , а нужно чтобы продолжала и В ТЕЧЕНИИ 30 секунд выполнялось какое-то действие.

Answer (score 0):

вам просто надо чтобы print('example') выполнялся каждую секунду?

если вам таковое надо, то в конце цикла напишите time.sleep(1)
Эта функция останавливает весь цикл на одну секунду.

Comment: Cпасибо, но это не то, что мне нужно!

Comment: а что вам нужно?